# Formatting json data into table React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have this state defined:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: false,
            customers:[],
            customer:{},
            products:[],
            product:{},
            orders:[],
            order:{},
            newForm:true,
            phoneNumbererror:null,
            shop:this.props.salon,
            value:'a',
            showTab:'none',
            slideIndex: 0,

        };
    }
```

With the following function which contains a fetch, I recieve an array of objects with responseData.

```
getHistory(){
        console.log("Log antes del fetch de customer id");
        console.log(this.state.customer._id);
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/orders/customer/'+this.state.customer._id, {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) =>
            {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((responseData) => {
                let orders = responseData.map((order) => {
                    return order.orderStatusChange ? Object.assign({}, order, {
                        status: order.orderStatusChange[0].status
                    }) : order;
                });
                this.setState({orders:orders});
                console.log("Log del responseData");
                console.log(responseData);
                console.log(responseData.orderStatusChange[0]);

            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }
```

This function is called in `handleCellClick`, where I pass some data from the consumer, such as the ID:

```
handleCellClick(y,x,row){
        this.setState({
            open:true,
            slideIndex: 0,
            newForm:false,
            customer:{...row}
        });
        this.getProfiles();
        this.getHistory();

    }
```

The JSON object obtained from the fetch and kept within `this.state.orders` looks like this:

```
(29) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
created:"2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"
customer:"59561f3f1d178e1966142ad7"
lastModified:"2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"
orderList:[]
orderStatusChange:Array(1)
0:{status: "5", comments: "Creado en back antes de pagar", _id: "595e5e0f60fbf65149916b7c", created: "2017-07-06T15:58:07.958Z"}
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
shop:"59108159bc3fc645704ba508"
totalAmount:4000
__v:0
_id:"595e5e0f60fbf65149916b7b"
__proto__:Object
```

As shown previously in the fetch, with this line `this.setState({orders:responseData})` I can pass `orders` to the table where I want the id, date, status and price to be displayed:

```
<DataTables
     height={'auto'}
     selectable={false}
     showRowHover={true}
     columns={HISTORY_TABLE_COLUMNS}
     data={this.state.orders}
     showCheckboxes={false}
     rowSizeLabel="Filas por página"
         />
```

The table called is:

```
    const HISTORY_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        key: '_id',
        label: 'Número de pedido',
        style:{width: '37%'}
    }, {
        key: 'created',
        label: 'Fecha del pedido',
        style:{width: '33%'}
    }, {
        key: 'status',
        label: 'Estado',
        style:{width: '13%'}
    }, {
        key: 'totalAmount',
        label: 'Total',
        style:{width: '17%'}
    }
];
```

**How can I format the price (totalAmount) to have 2 decimals and print next to it the € symbol?**

[CAPTURE FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuNvW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This solution works fine with node module material-ui-datatables version 0.18.0

> You can use render method in column settings to work on the column data.

```
const currencyToAppend = '€';
const HISTORY_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
  {
    ....
  }, {
    ....
  }, {
    key: 'totalAmount',
    label: 'Total',
    style:{width: '17%'}
    render: (amount, all) => {
        console.log(amount);
        console.log(all);
        return amount + ' ' + currencyToAppend;
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: It hasn't worked. My "all" is an unsused parameter, what is the purpose of it?

Comment: @Calicorio2, can you try printing both 'amount' and 'all'. I am too not aware.
I checked the npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-datatables which you are using. If you are getting 'amount' in console, this should work.

Comment: Ok I'll try it.

Comment: ohh is it. Ok give me some time will try and update you.

Comment: 'all' gives the total data object. I think you might be using the older version of DataTables. I just installed the latest "material-ui-datatables": "^0.18.2". Pl check yours

Comment: I can't understand why isn't working for me. I have the same code... Just read your suggestion of DataTables. I'll check it.

Comment: How can I update to the latest version? npm update DataTables?

Comment: What is the current version in your package.json for material-ui-datatables ?

Comment: You can just do: npm install material-ui-datatables --save

Comment: I tried your command and it stayed on the material-ui-datatables@0.16.9 version

Comment: do npm uninstall --material-ui-datatables --save and install again. But i think this is the problem. Updating to latest version should resolve your issue.

Comment: I think that's the problem too, but I have inserted your command to uninstall and then reinstall it and it stays on version 0.16.9... Why is this happening?

Comment: There might be some issue with you node version. Pl try npm install material-ui-datatables@0.18.2

Comment: You were right! That finally worked! :D Thank you for all the effort!

Comment: @Calicorio2.You can accept this as an answer, if it solved your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

While iterating data in table please do the following.

```
totalAmount.toFixed(2) + " €"
```

**Update:**
I would suggest this change should be done from backend, But any how for now you can handle it in `map` iterator where you are setting orders like  following

```
const currencyToAppend = ' €';

    let orders = responseData.map((order) => {
        return order.orderStatusChange ? Object.assign({}, order, {
          status: order.orderStatusChange[0].status
        },{
            totalAmount: order.totalAmount.toFixed(2) + currencyToAppend
        }) : Object.assign({}, order, {
            totalAmount: order.totalAmount.toFixed(2) + currencyToAppend
        });
    });
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Should I create another map function and iterate there?

Comment: @Calicorio2 Hey, am not sure about how your <DataTables /> component works. is it custom component or imported from any library ?

Comment: I've tried your answer updated and the result is a blank table. Nothing prints on it.

Comment: It goes straight to the catch "error"in the fetch function.

Comment: Please print development errors on console, like this `.catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }`

Answer (score 0):

To complement @dev's answer, I'd suggest to have render the cell as a function as that gives you more control

Check out the codesandox demo https://codesandbox.io/s/0VVwq645L

```
const HISTORY_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
  {
    key: "_id",
    label: "Número de pedido",
    style: { width: "37%" },
    value: item =>
      <code>
        {item._id}
      </code>
  },
  {
    key: "created",
    label: "Fecha del pedido",
    style: { width: "33%" },
    value: item => <Time value={item.created} />
  },
  {
    key: "status",
    label: "Estado",
    style: { width: "13%" },
    value: item =>
      <span>
        {item.status}
      </span>
  },
  {
    key: "totalAmount",
    label: "Total",
    style: { width: "17%" },
    value: item => <Amount value={item.totalAmount} currency="€"} />
  }
];
```

Comment: I've tried implementing part of your propose, but it hasn't worked either. I'll edit my question to show you what I've done.

Comment: I see that your data values are constructed in situ, so in my case are you suggesting to add a new parameter in the JSON object called currency to retrieve it?

Comment: Used mock data. It's upto you on how you want to append the `currency`. Edited, to hardcode the currency in the sample code